# Trying to convert a pre-made blank PDF Form into Javascript so I can make certain fields required

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, pdf-generation

Im trying to take a pdf form, say from the dmv, Like this one https://wisconsindot.gov/Documents/formdocs/mv2932.pdf. And take this document and put it into JavaScript so I can make some of the fields required. Is there a way to do this using this already premade form or would I have to create a completely new form?

Just looking for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The "Form Data Fields" can be set in the editor to "Required". Here I set the above mentioned PDF fields as such, and the border area turns RED.

One issue is that is not always as seen in the PDF reader, so of limited value unless you set the background red too.

However that makes no difference to a user as they will just as easily fill exactly what they wish to, in their favourite form filler or printout, and still submit incomplete forms.

I know because my partner (with limited sight) will do that on secured, mobile or tablet even If I dare to point out it's incomplete!

[image]

Basically PDF readers do not need to run scripts or colours, when showing a form field. Nor can they stop incomplete or separate *ad hoc* submissions, the only way is social engineering.

[image]

Use larger type in vivid colour NOT just at the top, but **close to the signature as possible** to remind the signatory it is their fault if a form is rejected due to error or omissions.

[image]